# Submitting form multiple times in .each() loop, only last submit sending

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to submit a form then update some values and submit it again. However, when I do this only the LAST version is being submitted. I get one error for `Unsafe Javascript attempt to access frame with URL domain2.com from frame with URL domain1 . Domains, Protocols and Ports must match.`

form code:

`<form id="hiddenform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://www.actonsoftware.com/acton/forms/userSubmit.jsp" accept-charset="UTF-8" target="tintest">`

the target is a hidden iframe with the `id="tintest"`

This is my code:

```
var tbody = $("#vmMainPage table:first tbody");
    var lng = tbody[0].rows.length - 1;
    var mnstr = "items: ";
    $("#vmMainPage table:first tbody tr").each(function(i){ 
        if ((i>0) && (i<(lng-3))) {
            item = $(this).children("td").children("a").children("strong").html();
            // quantity = "
            console.log(item);
            $("#hiddenform input#fld_0").val(item);
            var $tsta = "";
            for ( j=2; j<6; j++)
            {
                $tst = $("table:eq(2) tr:eq("+j+") td:eq(1)").html();
                $tsta = $tsta + $tst +", ";
            }
            $email = $("table:eq(2) tr:eq(6) td:eq(1)").html();
            $("#hiddenform input#fld_2").val($email+"_"+i);
            $("#hiddenform input#fld_1").val($tsta);
            $("#hiddenform").submit();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide the source url (generalized if necessary) and the "Action" url on `#hiddenform`?

Comment: Can you provide some information regarding the form, for example the `target` attribute, as if you just loop through something and trigger a bunch of `submit()`s, none of the earlier loops will have time to do anything as the page doesn't change anywhere.

Comment: i'm submitting it to acton (http://www.actonsoftware.com/acton/forms/userSubmit.jsp) , its software that handles things like email lists, the domain this code is on, is one of our websites- and thus has a different domain, I just don't understand why there would be an error on the first submit, but not the second (i havn't yet tried with more than 2 submits) the target is a hidden iframe

Comment: Are you certain it's the first submit that triggers the error and not the second?

Comment: try `setTimeout(function(){$("#hiddenform").submit();},3000)`

Comment: no, but on the acton end, i only recieve data from the 2nd submit.. is there some way I can test which causes the error? Is there no good way of submitting the same form multiple times in a for-loop? we're trying to get a separate submission for each item a customer orders

Comment: @mplungjan: tried setTimeout it just made it submit the 2nd stuff 3 seconds later.. I'm looking in chrome dev tools, and I only see 1 POST of the data

Comment: Create an iframe per submission and target to that

Comment: Okay, I'll try that, I'll have to create an unknown number of iframes though and give them id's like "iframe_"+i

Comment: @mplungjan: that worked so i can accept it an as answer if you write it, I wish I could do it a less "heavy" way (not creating multiple iframes)... is there a way to just $.post the data even though its enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure your requests are not interfering with each other, you can create an iframe for each request and target that.

this can be done with DOM
    var cnt=0;

```
var ifr = document.createElement("iframe");
ifr.name="ifr"+(cnt++);
ifr.style.display="none"
document.getElementById("iframeContainer").appendChild(ifr);
document.forms[0].target=ifr.name;
document.forms[0].submit()
```

or jQuery

```
cnt++
$("#iframeContainer").append('<iframe src="about:blank" name="ifr'+cnt+'"></iframe>');
$("#hiddenform").attr("target","ifr"+cnt);
$("#hiddenform").submit();
```